# Проблема с сохранением данных в MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

ПРЕДУПРЕЖДЕНИЕ: в использовании MongoDB я новичок, поэтому ошибка может быть максимально простой.

Пишу на Node.js, пакет, который я использовал - mongoose.

Файл index.js:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const MongoDB =
  "mongodb+srv://[юзернейм]:[мойпароль]@nodedb.rbs7d.mongodb.net/shiftodb";
const User = require("./assets/models/userModel.js");

mongoose.connect(MongoDB);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on(
  "error",
  console.error.bind(console, "MongoDB connection error. Check the code again.")
);

db.once("open", () => {
  console.log("MongoDB has been connected.");
  console.log("created new model");
  const user = new User({ name: "Alex" });
  console.log("user", user);
});
```

Далее, в папке с проектом у меня находится папка assets, в ней папки models и sсhemas, в которых лежат модели и схемы соответственно.

Вот код файла userSchema.js:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
})

module.exports = userSchema;
```

И файла userModel.js:

```js
const userSchema = require("../schemas/userSchema.js");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Не думаю, что проблема в них, но все же. После того, как я запускаю файл через node index.js, все работает.
Вот вывод в консоли:

```
(node:52144) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
(node:52144) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new 
Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
MongoDB has been connected.
created new model
user { _id: 5f06fd882bf05ccbb018617b, name: 'Alex' }
```

И вроде бы все хорошо, вот только в БД это не сохраняется.
[image: Скрин вида БД через MongoDB Compass]

Однако, индех _id использовался, и это записано.
[image: Еще один скрин]

В консоли mongo аналогичная ситуация. Скрин прикладывать не буду, ибо перебор.
Вопрос: почему не добавляется в базу данных информация? Нужно использовать дополнительный метод, или же у меня где-то ошибка?
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const user = new User({ name: "Alex" });
user.save(function (err, userAlex){/*...*/});
```

сохранить забыли =)

можно без callback `user.save()`

можно  promiseLike `user.save().then( userAlex => /*...*/ )`